# How to get background colour to 'overflow' behind a spritsheet image on hover?

Tags: css

I am working on a [website](http://optcflairbot.tumblr.com/) where a user can select an icon and send it as a request to one of my bots.

I've already got it sorted out. I'm mainly just working on improving the aesthetics.

What I want to happen is, when hovering over an icon (or even selecting it), it shows a light blue background colour to indicate that it's been selected, because right now there is nothing to indicate a chosen icon except for the div at the very top (which isn't always in sight when you scroll further down).

The code I have atm is:

```
.flair:hover, .selected{
        background-color: #3498db;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
```

I've tried adding some padding but since each image is in a spritesheet, it will overlap with other images.

I've also tried using a border instead to emulate the same effect, but hovering over an image would slightly move the other images due to the border being applied and it gets annoying.

Is there some way I can get my background-color to 'overflow' behind the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you add a transparent border add the begining as a placeholder and change your margins since borders gonna add some space

```
.flair {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-clip : padding-box;
  margin-right:6px;
  margin-top:6px;
}
```

and then you color it with some additional glow when hovering

```
.flair:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #3498db;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
}
```

Comment: Well that was an extremely easy fix to my problem.. I must be running low on creativity! Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, there's a slight problem with that. It now shows bits of the other sprite images. I've updated the website to reflect the changes you proposed so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The source spritesheet looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/RkcLfXV.png). As you can see, all the images are clumped together with no padding in between. The transparent border is show bits of the other images surrounding it (if that makes sense).

Comment: @antonlab Oh i get it. I updated the answer with `background-clip` and some `margin` modifications.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for this time, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
.flair:hover, .selected {
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This still causes each image to move slightly while hovering.

Comment: Yeah. You beat me on this one mate. This should be the checked answer ;)